# Merge 2 JSON objects with similar keys: ReactJS

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, api, rest

This is how my API response looks like currently, I want to merge the columns where the common column is ID. This how the response looks like currently.

```
formattedData 
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, date1: null, status: "PENDING", c: "Y", d: null, …}
1: {id: 2, date1: null, status: "OPEN", c: "Y", d: null, …}
2: {id: 1, a: "Elegant LLC", b: "Suparna Bose"}
3: {id: 2, a: "Work LLC", b: "Suparna Bose"}
4: {id: 3, a: "Professionals LLC", b: "Suparna Bose"}
```

expected output:

```
formattedData 
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, date1: null, status: "PENDING", c: "Y", d: null, a: "XYZ LLC", b: "Suparna Bose" …}
1: {id: 2, date1: null, status: "OPEN", c: "Y", d: null, a: "ABC LLC", b: "Suparna Bose"…}
4: {id: 3, a: "Professionals LLC", b: "Suparna Bose"}
```

This is how my code looks like currently. Taken the 2 responses and pushed in an array. Can I somehow merge the second response with the first

```
axios.all([p1, p2, p3])
  .then(
    axios.spread((...responses) => {
      const responseOne = responses[0];
      const responseTwo = responses[1];
    responseOne.data.map(function(responseObj,index) {
      Object.keys(responseObj).map(function(key,index) {
        if(key === 'key1'){
          let dummyObj = {
            'id' : responseObj['key1']['id'],
            'date1' : responseObj['key1']['date1'],
            'status' : responseObj['key1']['status']['desc'],
            'c' : responseObj['key1']['c'],
            'd' : responseObj['key1']['d'],
            'e' : responseObj['key1']['e'],
            'f' : responseObj['key1']['f']
          }
          formattedData.push(dummyObj);
        }
    })
    })
    responseTwo.data.map(function(responseObj,index) {
      Object.keys(responseObj).map(function(key,index) {
        if(key === 'key2'){
          let dummyObj = {
            'id' : responseObj['key2']['id'],
            'a' : responseObj['key2']['a'],
            'b' : responseObj['key2']['b']
          }
          formattedData.push(dummyObj);
        }
    })
    })
```

Had written this piece of code for merging the second response to the first, but not sure where to go from here

```
let copy = formattedData;
    function isId(IdValue){
      copy.map(function(eachData, index) {
        if(eachData['Id'] === IdValye){
          responseTwo.data.map(function(eachResponseObj,index){
            Object.keys(eachResponseObj).map(function(key,index) {
              if(key === 'key2'){
                console.log(eachResponseObj['key2']['desc']);
              }}
            )
          }
        )
      }
    })}
    isId();
```

Comment: `map` returns an array. If you're not going to use it, just use `forEach`. Also, there are a number of questions about this kind of behavior on Stack Overflow. Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any additional code.

Comment: Done, had written this piece of code for merging the second json value to the first

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example of what `response` looks like. Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))` to get the output (or look at the raw JSON from Network Tools) so that we can see to real data as opposed to console cruft as seen in the example of `formattedData`.

Comment: Not letting me edit in the question, what's coming is
`
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "a": null,
    "b": "PENDING",
    "c": "Y"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "a": null,
    "b": "OPEN",
    "c": "Y"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "Elegant LLC",
    "assignTo": "Suparna Bose"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "desc": "Work LLC",
    "assignTo": "Suparna Bose"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "desc": "Professionals LLC",
    "assignTo": "Suparna Bose"
  }
]
`

Comment: Expected: `
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "a": null,
    "b": "PENDING",
    "c": "Y",
    "desc": "Elegant LLC",
    "assignTo": "Suparna Bose"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "a": null,
    "b": "OPEN",
    "c": "Y",
    "desc": "Work LLC",
    "assignTo": "Suparna Bose"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "desc": "Professionals LLC",
    "assignTo": "Suparna Bose"
  }
]
`